# Facebook app review team taking too much time

Tags: facebook

Why facebook review team taking too much time to review the app. Its already 3 weeks but still no response from Facebook team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question to begin with. (Hardly a question at all actually.)

Comment: Because they stopped reviewing apps for a long time. So now there are a lot of apps that want to be reviewed. They also changed it so almost all old apps need to be rereviewed.

Comment: How long did it wind up taking?

Comment: This is not an actual question and shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there are some delays lately, maybe wait a bit more:
This is what I got from the FAQ.

Due to changes to the review process and the high volume of submissions expected, it may take several weeks for submitted apps to complete review.

Please provide as much info as possible to help the reviewer, including clear screenshots, detailed step-by-step instructions and a screencast recording of your app and its Facebook integration.